# Does iMessage cost extra if I have another device?

Tags: messages

I have iMessage on my iPhone 5, and I signed in to iMessage on my iPad 2.

Will it cost extra to have iMessage on my iPad 2?

I think iMessage might be free but I'm still curious.

Comment: What makes you think it cost something in the first place? Or why would they charge for another device? Were you ever prompted for any sort of payment method? (The answer, of course is, no, they won't charge you)

Answer (score 2):

Messages is free if you are texting someone with the email address ( which is the only thing available on the iPad). If you are on the iPhone and texting another phone, then it will count as a text for the service provider. However, any iOS 5 and above device has messages installed and it is free.

Answer (score 1):

**iMessage is entirely free.**

You can use any iOS or OSX 10.8 (or greater) device to iMessage any other iOS or OSX 10.8 (or greater) that has iMessage enabled. You can enable any iMessage account on as many compatible devices that you would like for no additional charge.

That said, there is one slight caveat of which I'm sure you are aware. If you text, from iPhone Messages.app, someone's cell phone number who doesn't have iMessage (or doesn't have it enabled on their cell phone), then your service provider may (depending on your plan) charge you for a SMS text message. This is an important distinction, because, unlike what iKiel2012 said, all other iPhone *iMessaging* is free.

Also keep in mind the difference between "Messages" - a particular iOS/OSX app - and "iMessage" - a somewhat alternative to SMS text messages. You only mentioned iMessage - the service offered by Apple - which is entirely free no matter who you iMessage (but again, one **cannot** iMessage a non-iMessage user).